# get archive.org to save the latest copy a page? (its copies of this page are very out of date)

Tags: archive.org

I looked up this page on archive.org

https://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-scratching-card-shuffling-noise-in-windows

https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-scratching-card-shuffling-noise-in-windows

It has copies for 4 months. march 2013-june 2013, archived when the page was gone. (so those archives from then are as good as saving a 404 error)

So for the last 6 months archive.org hasn't updated their copy of the page.

Is there any way to get archive.org to save the page as it is for the current date, because it has changed since they last saved it?

Comment: From what I recall, the Wayback machine purposefully doesn't have pages fresher than six months. I'll see if I can find the policy.

Comment: I have seen that written there but this is longer than 6 months.

Comment: @AlE. ah I notice the page says up to 24 months.. doh. well, we'll see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a form for saving a copy on https://archive.org/web/web.php:

[image]

You can also go to https://web.archive.org/web/save/{url-you-want-to-save} to make the Wayback Machine take a snapshot of the current state. This is what happens when you use the above form.